# SCL011 contactless Card Reader and Mifare 1k(classic) authentification

Tags: mifare, contactless-smartcard, pcsc

I have SCL011 Card Reader and need to read/write Mifare 1k cards. But I just can't get over Authentification step....

Card Reader should handle Mifare 1k cards:

- Antenna ISO/IEC 14443 compliant design
- Baudrate up to 848 Kbps
- Supported standards:
- ISO/IEC 14443-4 Typ A & B
- MIFARE: Classic 1K and 4K, DESFire, Ultralight, MIFARE Plus
- FeliCa™
- NFC forum tag type 1, 2, 3, 4
- iCLASS UID*

I have also updated to the latest firmware (1.20)
http://support.identive-group.com/dfu_fw.php?OS=windows&readerno=85

card is connected and I can read the UID of the card with **ff ca 00 00 00**
I have also tried to read the sector directly without authorization **ff b0 00 00 10** and I get message:

> 69 82 : Command not allowed. Security status not satisfied.

it means I need authorize myself, but if I try **ff 82 00 00 06 ff ff ff ff ff ff** or any other standard keys I always get back:

> 69 88 : Command not allowed. SM data objects incorrect.

funny thing is, that I can read and write this card without problems with my Nexus and Lumia phones...

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

keys I have already tried:

```
* ff 82 00 00 06 ff ff ff ff ff ff
* ff 82 00 00 06 a0 b0 c0 d0 e0 f0
* ff 82 00 00 06 a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 f1
* ff 82 00 00 06 a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5
* ff 82 00 00 06 b0 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5
* ff 82 00 00 06 4d 3a 99 c3 51 dd
* ff 82 00 00 06 1a 98 2c 7e 45 9a
* ff 82 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00
* ff 82 00 00 06 d3 f7 d3 f7 d3 f7
* ff 82 00 00 06 aa bb cc dd ee ff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:** Please google/search "**Multiprotocol contactless mobile reader, Reference manual**" or "**SCL01X Multiprotocol contactless stationary reader**".
It is a very nice references to start with SCL reader's APDUs. There are some examples inside.

**Answer:** In your case **P2** value in the APDU Command incorrect and you got **SW1SW2 = 0x6988  - "Key number not valid"**.

```
Where P2 can have the following values (please refer to MIFARE documentation from NXP for
further details on what is key A and Key B):
• 0x60 to use the Key A
• 0x61 to use the Key B
```